# -[ViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance - on tableview scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer, respondstoselector

Similar Questions has already been asked at SO. My case is little different so I am posting as a new Question.

I have got a scrollView as a main view for controller. It contains two subviews:

1. Scrollview having a UIView as child.
2. Tableview containing some **numeric** Textfields.

I have attached a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to child scrollview, so that user can dismiss keyboard from any textfield.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tableTouched:)];
[topScrollview addGestureRecognizer:tap1];
tap1.delegate = self;

-(void) tableTouched:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    [portTable endEditing:YES];
    portTable.scrollEnabled = YES;
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.textLabel.font = myFont;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
        {
            UILabel *tradeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(9, 5, 60, 40)];
            tradeLabel.text = @"Trade";
            tradeLabel.font = myFont;
            tradeLabel.textColor = [ColorCodes sharedManager].orangeTextColor;
            tradeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [cell.contentView insertSubview:tradeLabel aboveSubview:cell.textLabel];
            break;
         }
//similar cases
}
return cell;

}
```

Now if I keep scrolling tableview for sometime, I get crash with the message mentioned in title. Stack trace using instruments is as follows:

[image: Stack Trace]

[image]

I can't understand the reason for negative reference count my controller. I haven't set any scrollview delegate, then why reference count becomes -1?

I have already tried attaching gesture to main scrollview, tableview itself and to the child UIView, but still getting the same crash. Please someone point me in right direction.. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Another stack trace I just got:

[image]

Comment: convert your @propery from `retain` to `strong`

Comment: Put code of cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: i haven't set any @property to retain. All are strong. Btw both are almost same.

Comment: @iPatel my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has got many custom controls initialized. Are you sure you want to see it?

Comment: just put it as .. - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

         /// Put your code here.
     }

      /// Put your code here.

    return cell;
}

Comment: may be issue in reusable feature of cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully found the bug. It was because of a custom control in a cell. It was retaining and releasing explicitly being non-ARC (but included in ARC project). Gesture was causing no problem. Removing those lines solved my problem.